# R Highcharter - highlight same group in multiple stacked columns chart + order groups in columns

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

R newbie here :) 
I have recently started using R library Highcharter as an alternative to ggplot2.

This is the sample code I am currently working on:

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)

## Sample dataframe

YEAR <- c(2019,2020,2021) 
CATEGORY <- c("dog", "cat", "mouse")
SAMPLE_DATA <- expand.grid(YEAR, CATEGORY)
names(SAMPLE_DATA)[1] <- "CATEGORY"
names(SAMPLE_DATA)[2] <- "YEAR"
SAMPLE_DATA$VALUE <- runif(n = 9, min = 400, max = 900) 


## Chart 

SAMPLE_DATA <- SAMPLE_DATA %>% 
  group_by(YEAR, CATEGORY) %>% 
  summarise(VALUE = sum(VALUE, na.rm = T)) 
  
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(data = SAMPLE_DATA, hcaes(x = YEAR, y = round(VALUE,0), group = CATEGORY), type = "column") %>%
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal"))
```

What I am trying to do is:

1. Sort how the group "CATEGORY" is piled in each column, based on ascending/descending "VALUE"
2. Have that effect which highlights the same group in all columns as you hover over it

Does anyone have an idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer but I believe this is what you want.

Adding the data again because I think you swapped some column names on accident:

```
YEAR <- c(2019,2020,2021) 
CATEGORY <- c("dog", "cat", "mouse")
SAMPLE_DATA <- expand.grid(YEAR, CATEGORY)
names(SAMPLE_DATA)[1] <- "YEAR"
names(SAMPLE_DATA)[2] <- "CATEGORY"
SAMPLE_DATA$VALUE <- runif(n = 9, min = 400, max = 900) 


## Chart 

SAMPLE_DATA <- SAMPLE_DATA %>% 
  group_by(YEAR, CATEGORY) %>% 
  summarise(VALUE = sum(VALUE, na.rm = T))
```

Creating plot:

```
SAMPLE_DATA %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(YEAR = factor(YEAR) %>% fct_reorder(VALUE, .desc = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(year_index = as.numeric(YEAR)) %>% 
  hchart(
    type = "column",
    hcaes(x = year_index,
          y = VALUE,
          group = CATEGORY,
          name = YEAR),
  ) %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category", labels = list(step = 1)) %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(series = list(stacking = TRUE))
```

[image: example1]